# Angular ng-init pass element to scope

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way to get the current element where my ng-init is currently binded on?

For example:

```
<div ng-init="doSomething($element)"></div>
```

I believe that there is a way for ng-click but I can't do this using ng-init like this:

```
<div ng-click="doSomething($event)"></div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.doSomething = function(e){ 
    var element = angular.element(e.srcElement); 
}
```

How do I do this with ng-init?

Comment: Tried in my workspace. It is working perfectly fine. Check whether you are passing correct values.

Comment: You can write a custom directive and call the controller method from inside there and pass the element as parameter.

Comment: Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/88T4F/

Comment: @CodeHater Thanks. The directive approach will work for me.

Comment: And because AngularJS does not advocate DOM manipulation inside controllers, I suggest you handle that inside directive itself.

Comment: Thanks @CodeHater (Himanshu). It worked for me.

Comment: @CodeHater nice solution, but unable to add class with element. something like below, am I correct? angular.element(el).addClass('visible');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it.

As @CodeHater said, handling DOM manipulation in a directive is a better solution than engaging controller with the element.

Answer (score 8):

Your HTML:

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div my-dir></div>
</div>
```

Your Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [], function () {});

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.doSomething = function (e) {
        alert(e);
    };
});

app.directive('myDir', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.doSomething(element);
    };
});
```

From above, `element` will be your DOM object.

Comment: Just a side note: The `element` will be available, but not all siblings or childs.

Comment: @WashingtonGuedes thanks reminder. i have removed the redundancy.

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for similar thing but finally I created one more directive added to the child div element. In the directive code block I get the element object and placed all my event related function and other instructions over there. Also, I add the element to $scope object, this help me to use this object else where as well and no need to find it every time I need it.

Comment: That sounds like it could be a useful approach.  Could you please share some code that you think will help solve the problem?